# phpseclib file uploading with 0 byte

Tags: php, phpseclib

```
 include('Net/SFTP.php');

    $sftp = new Net_SFTP('000.000.0.00');
    if (!$sftp->login('root', 'h0dus0ft')) {
        exit('Login Failed');
    }

    //Connection getting succeed

    var_dump($sftp->put('/var/www/html/jigar/filmfile.zip', '/home/jigar/Downloads/filmfile.zip',NET_SFTP_LOCAL_FILE)); 
    //Boolean false all time
    var_dump($sftp->getSFTPErrors()); 
    //getting empty array
```

File is getting uploaded successfully but with 0 bytes, don't know what is problem here.

some help would be appreciate please.

Comment: Can you post the SSH logs? You can get them by doing `define('NET_SSH2_LOGGING', 2);` at the top and then by doing `echo $ssh->getLog();` after the `$sftp->put()` call. With the logs we should, hopefully, be able to figure out what's happening.

Comment: Thanks @neubert , let me do that.

Answer (score 4):

- The file was corrupted during transfer. This can be caused by connectivity issues between your computer and your server. We can partially test this by running 'traceroute domain.com' in Terminal (Mac users only, Windows uses tracery).
- Full disk space on the server. If the disk space is full on the server, it will cause issues similar to this with your upload.
- Charset issues. Your Grid charset is UTF-8. Occasionally, if you upload a file that isn't in this charset, you may encounter issues.
- The file was corrupted prior to upload. Please ensure that all files you upload are functioning correctly.

Comment: Thanks, but there is no chance of connectivity problem or a disc space, second thing is I am uploading file from local to another my local area network. So, might be a problem of charset don't know. Could you help me?

Comment: yes, it's definitely Charter set issues please check your charset is UTF-8.

Comment: That is the thing I don't know how to check and change

Comment: Please refer to this link for more info http://andy-carter.com/blog/connecting-to-sftp-with-php